# Exchange 2016 "Microsoft.Office.CsmSdk" dependencie

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2016

I have been assigned the task of setting up a Windows Server 2012 R2 (Standard) with Exchange 2016.

I have managed to get Exchange 2016 installed but now I'm faced with this error (see screenshot)

[image: See below the error I'm getting]

Any idea why I'm getting this? and how do i fix it? (Google isn't helping here)

Comment: Start by getting rid of Classic Shell, or better yet start from scratch with a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: This was a fresh install, only a couple of programs on there.

Comment: You've got Classic Shell installed, right? That's some kind of third party Shell replacement or something like that? What other third party software is installed?

Comment: classic shell, notepad ++ & Chrome that is it (I'm really new to this, learning on the job!)

Comment: My (strong) suggestion would be to reinstall Windows from scratch without installing any third party software. There's no way to know right now if any of the third party software that's installed is the cause of the Exchange installation errors.

Comment: Never use a server like a desktop. It should have nothing installed that's not directly related to the server's function. When you format and reinstall, leave off notepad++, chrome, and everything else that's not exchange or something directly needed for it. That stuff belongs on your workstation.